# assigning List[] to HashMap in Java

Tags: java, hashmap, hashtable

I am trying to fill a `HashMap` by a `String[]`, but it returns null

```
HashMap<String[], String[]> h = new HashMap<String[], String[]>();
String[] part2 = new String[100];
String[] part1 = new String[100];
int n = 0;
for (String a : tempFindings) {
    String[] parts = a.split("\\.");
    part1[n] = parts[0]; 
    part2[n] = parts[1];                    
    n++;
}
h.put(part2, part1);
```

any clue how I can have all my list splited in a HashMap?

EDIT:

I also tried

HashMap<String[], String[]> h = new HashMap<String[], String[]>();
for(String a : tempFindings)
{
String[] parts = a.split("\.");
part1 = parts[0];
part2 = parts[1];

```
                h.put(part2, part1);
            }
```

buth.put each time rewrites itself.

I am wondering why it does not behave like this example:

```
// Mapping string values to int keys 
        hash_map.put(10, "Geeks"); 
        hash_map.put(15, "4"); 
        hash_map.put(20, "Geeks"); 
        hash_map.put(25, "Welcomes"); 
        hash_map.put(30, "You");
```

if you .put one by one it creates a hashmap with several alues but if I put it in a loop it rewrites itself.

Comment: Only one question: "WHY?"

Comment: I need to sort my list based on the file extension

Comment: So why do you use ```String[]``` type as a ```key```? You can use ```Map<String, File[]> map```. ```String``` - to save extension type and ```File[]``` to store all files with that extension

Comment: Are you sure you want key and value to be `String[]`? If yes please give an example for input and output.

Comment: You may want Map<String, ArrayList<String>>

Comment: I added an EDIT part.please take a look at iz. and can you please suggest me the code?

Comment: Are you sure you are not over complicating the task? If you need to sort a list of file names based on extension you can do it in 2 or 3 lines using a comparator.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a list of file names, something like:

```
List<String> myFiles = List.of("foo.txt", "foo.sql", "foo.dat", "foo.exe");
```

you can sort your list by extension using a comparator by extarcting the extension using `String#substring` and `String#lastIndexOf`

Example:

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> myFiles = List.of("foo.txt", "foo.sql", "foo.dat", "foo.exe");
        Comparator<String> byExtension = (f1, f2) -> f1.substring(f1.lastIndexOf('.'))
                .compareTo(f2.substring(f2.lastIndexOf('.')));

        List<String> sorted = myFiles.stream().sorted(byExtension).collect(Collectors.toList());

        System.out.println(myFiles);
        System.out.println(sorted);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you might need to change your `Map<String[], String[]>` to `Map<String, String[]>` if you want to store a `String` type - as a file extension, and a `String[]` array as all file names.

But if I understood correctly the author needs:

> I need to sort my list based on the file extension

And I hope you need to store it in Map like a key - extension and values - all names.

Might be a solution:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Main2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<String, List<String>> map = getAllFilesGroupedByExtension("C://");
        for(String one : map.keySet()){
            System.out.println(map.get(one).toString());
        }
    }
    public static Optional<String> getExtension(String filename) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(filename)
                .filter(f -> f.contains("."))
                .map(f -> f.substring(filename.lastIndexOf(".") + 1));
    }
    public static Map<String, List<String>> getAllFilesGroupedByExtension(String path){
        File[] filesList = new File(path).listFiles();
        Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        for(File file : filesList){
            if (file.isFile())
                if (map.containsKey(getExtension(file.getName()).orElseThrow())){
                    List<String> tempList = map.get(getExtension(file.getName()).orElseThrow());
                    tempList.add(file.getName());
                    map.put(getExtension(file.getName()).orElseThrow(), tempList);
                } else {
                    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
                    tempList.add(file.getName());
                    map.put(getExtension(file.getName()).orElseThrow(), tempList);
                }
        }
        return map;
    }
}
```

or If you need `List<File>` you can use this:

```
public static Map<String, List<File>> getAllFilesGroupedByExtension(String path){
        File[] filesList = new File(path).listFiles();
        return Arrays.stream(filesList)
                .filter(File::isFile)
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(file -> getExtension(file.getName()).orElseThrow()));
    }
```